# Is there a term in Journalism that means "words written as they will be printed"?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

In charge of a workplace newsletter, I constantly receive E-mails with requests that I include notices in the next issue, but they will read like this:

> "Please post an announcement for Bob's birthday party, on Tuesday. Tell people to bring one dish, it will be a potluck."

I want to encourage people to actually send us the text that they actually want to appear in the newsletter. I end up having to rewrite their message, which can introduce errors, which they will blame on me; and often the actual message isn't any longer than what they send me, so no extra work for them.

Is there a genuine term, probably a noun, in Journalism used to describe such "words, exactly as they will appear when in print"?

Comment: "Please email me your text word-for-word."

Comment: You might be looking for the word [***verbatim***](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/verbatim); usually, the publication states that announcement will appear _verbatim_ in the issue of the indicated date.

Comment: I understand its simple to communicate this, but wondering if there is a special term for this, after all, we will also have students help, so its useful they learn that.

Comment: The two options that have been supplied _are_ the 'special terms' - I don't know of any other.

Comment: @Village, students help what?

Comment: Please send me your **verbatim message** or message verbatim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term is *copy*.

> **copy** *noun*
> 3 *mass noun* Matter to be printed.
> ‘copy for the next issue must be submitted by the beginning of the month’
> [-Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/copy)

However, if the others are not familiar with this usage, you might be better off asking for the *text* that they want printed.
The following example comes from [cakemessage.com](http://www.cakemessage.com/), a custom cake message maker:

> Enter cake text below

> YOUR TEXT APPEARS ON THE CAKE

Comment: I don't think "copy" is quite right, because one would expect the "copy for the next issue" to be modified by the editor prior to printing - it gets across the idea of "raw text intended to be published", but not of "we will print exactly the words that you specify".

Comment: @psmears That sounds like a *draft* or a *proof*.

Comment: A journalist might submit a *draft* of an article, and that would be *copy*, but a *proof* is different. And it doesn't take away from the fact that *copy* doesn't mean *will be printed word for word*.

Comment: @psmears Yes, *proof* goes the other way, back to the author. However, *copy* doesn’t intrinsically carry the notion of something submitted for editing. The dictionary entry supports this. It may well be edited, but the intent of *copy* is that it is the text to be printed, not a description of text to be printed. If you disagree, please provide evidence of your view.

Comment: "Copy" just means "text" in journalistic jargon; you're right it won't *necessarily* get edited, but the usual situation is that submitted copy will be edited. The question asked for something to express "words, *exactly* as they will appear when in print" (emphasis mine); the word "copy" (on its own) doesn't capture the "exactly".

Answer (score 4):

From comments:

- > "Please email me your text word-for-word." — Kate Bunting

*Word for word* means ‘In exactly the same or, when translated, exactly equivalent words.’ [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/word_for_word)]

---

- > You might be looking for the word [***verbatim***](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/verbatim); usually, the publication states that announcement will appear *verbatim* in the issue of the indicated date. — Jeff Zeitlin

*Verbatim* means ‘In exactly the same words as were used originally.’ [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/verbatim)]